# Host at Facebook to avoid traffic or other possibilities?

Tags: facebook

is it possible to let my own facebook apps (not generating revenue) being hosted by facebook?

The problem is that by using the iframe-version the traffic/requests are killing the server :-(
But I need to connect to a database and print/calculate values, so I think there is no other way than hosting everything on own servers. But maybe there are things I don't know.

What is the way you would go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Facebook has an option to host apps, at least not that I've ever heard of or was quickly able to find on their developers site.

Honestly, when it comes to hosting a high-demand website, there's no free way to do it.  Resources cost money.  You can pick from tons of hosting providers and see who gives you the features you need at the best rate.  Maybe some will offer free hosting if you include ads in the Facebook app, maybe some will offer free hosting for other means, etc.

For a non-revenue-generating app, when it becomes popular and successful and requires real resources to keep it running, it's generally time to start thinking about how to generate revenue from it.  Maybe use it as a free gateway app to other revenue-generating apps (a loss leader), maybe have ads, maybe use it to generate useful marketing data, etc.  For a successful site it may involve a good bit of personal investment and risk before the profits roll in (Facebook being a good, though extreme and uncommon example of this).

Answer (score 2):

You have to host the application on your own, there's no way that FB does it for you.